How can I allow the player to move objects around in Unity3D?
So I want to allow the player to move containers (GameObject) in the world. I have googled this, but only found 2D solutions. This will be a mod for the game The Long Dark, so it must work without altering the item in its source, since I cant do that. Mods make use of Melon Loader.
I would like to also be able to move these objects if they have items in them, which a previous mod could not do (previous mod's code doesn't help as it is too old and the code has changed).
I am entirely unsure how to do this, so dont have any code to show.

normally the complaint is reverse.. look at navmesh
